# C# multiple Windows Forms cannot reference

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I have 2 Windows `form1` (monitor 1 - 1920x1080) and `form2` (monitor 2 - 1920x1080), form 1 (monitor 1) has 3 functions need to call function from form2 (monitor 2).

I have to create form2 (screen2) 3 times in `Form1`, but they won't be same form2 right? Any recommendation to solve this issue?

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    // Variables
    private Form1 _ParentForm;    // Add this here

    // Constructor
    public Form2(Form1 parentForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _ParentForm = parentForm;   // Add this here
    }

    public void Rec_image()
    {
        // Form 2 Image
        PictureBox1.Show();
        PictureBox2.Hide();
    }

    public void Charging()
    {
        // Form 2 Image
        PictureBox6.Hide();
        PictureBox1.Hide();
        PictureBox2.Hide();
        PictureBox3.Hide();
        PictureBox4.Hide();
        PictureBox5.Hide();
        PictureBox7.Show();
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
        form2.Show();
    }
    
    private async void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
        form2.Rec_image();
    }
    
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
        form2.Charging();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You understand how to keep a reference to a form in a field, so why not do that in `Form1`?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Form2 ( 2nd monitor) is having function Rec_image() to show or hide image and it's linking to PictureBox in 2nd monitor.   And in Form1 (1st monitor), it has function to display Form2 ( 2nd monitor); and another Button2_Click to call Form2.Rec_image().

Comment: Is there anyway to create instance for Form2 in form 1 so all functions inside Form1 can reference to Form2 instance?

Comment: put the reference of Form2 instance in a field and not a local var

Comment: It seems I cannot define Form2 instance as public var? It's giving an error "this" cannot reference                                                                                                                      public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
}

Comment: You have `private Form1 _ParentForm;` in `Form2`. You just need to do `private Form2 _Form2;` in `Form1`. Same thing.

Comment: thanks Engmativity for feedback. It solve my problem!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the reference to `Form2` instance in a field of `Form1` class and you can access the same instance again and again.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 _form2; // field

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form2 = new Form2(this);
        _form2.Show();
    }
    
    private async void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form2.Rec_image();
    }
    
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form2.Charging();
    }

}
```